# How do I stop optimize imports from removing Kotlin Android Extensions imports?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Running optimize imports on Android Studio 3.1.3 is causing my kotlin android extension imports to be removed even when they're being used. Anyone know how to resolve this issue or exclude kotlinx imports from being removed by optimize imports?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Kotlin extension perhaps? Have you checked the issue tracker if it's been logger as a bug there?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Kotlin version 1.2.40, you will likely experience this issue.

Upgrade your Kotlin and Kotlin-android-extensions version in your build.gradle files to 1.2.50

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.2.50"
```

Comment: I still seem to be experiencing this in 1.2.50

Comment: Did you make sure to invalidate caches and clean your project after the update, as well as make sure your Kotlin version is up to date everywhere?

Comment: I'll go ahead and try that. Thanks Jaques. I'll make sure to mark it as the solution if it does work.